# How to include related Reference entity of related Collection entity with single query

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have following models for Members writing Reviews on Movies -

```cs
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}

public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public Member Member { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

I want to query Movies so that each Movie includes all it's related Reviews and each Review includes it's related Member. I can do it in a two fold way -

```cs
var movies = await _context.Movies.Include(p=>p.Reviews).ToListAsync();
var reviews = await _context.Reviews.Include(p => p.Member).ToListAsync();
```

How can I do it with a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get additional related data to be further included based on a related type that was just included:

```
var movies = await _context.Movies.Include(p=>p.Reviews).ThenInclude(r => r.Member).ToListAsync();
```

I've found that IntelliSense may not work for ThenInclude on collections but the data is included correctly.

I.e. when you type

```
ThenInclude(r => r.
```

You may get options for 'Add', 'Aggregate<>' etc extension methods but not the property name you want to then include. Just type the name anyway and it works.

Comment: Thanks. IntelliSense was the case, and so I didn't bother to type the name forcibly. Its working.

Answer (score 0):

You an use ThenInclude

var movies = await _context.Movies.Include(p=>p.Reviews).ThenInclude(x=>x.Member).ToListAsync();

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even though the lambda parameter in `ThenInclude` doesn't list `Member`, looks like it works.